# JSTL dsp:input submit button value HTML entites not decoded

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, atg, oracle-commerce

PFB the JSP code,

```
<fmt:message var="applyText" key="checkout.order.summary.coupon.apply" />
<dsp:input iclass="btn green rev validatePromoCode" id="atg_store_applyCoupon" bean="CouponFormHandler.claimCoupon" type="submit" value="${applyText}" />
```

submit button value is coming from property file, PFB,

```
checkout.order.summary.coupon.apply = Einl&ouml;sen
```

Button value text is not encoded in UI, Expected value for the button should be **Einlösen**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a different encoding? `Einl\u00F6sen` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use dsp:tagAttribute:**

```
<fmt:message var="applyText" key="checkout.order.summary.coupon.apply" />
<dsp:input iclass="btn green rev validatePromoCode" id="atg_store_applyCoupon" bean="CouponFormHandler.claimCoupon" type="submit">
    <dsp:tagAttribute name="value" value="${applyText}"/>
</dsp:input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue in the past.  Believe the way I got around this by nesting the `<c:out />` tag within the `<dsp:input />`:

```
<fmt:message var="applyText" key="checkout.order.summary.coupon.apply" />
<dsp:input iclass="btn green rev validatePromoCode" id="atg_store_applyCoupon" bean="CouponFormHandler.claimCoupon" type="submit" value="<c:out value='${applyText}'/>" />
```

Comment: I believe the `c:out` tag escapes the special characters appropriately.